# Microsoft as Identity provider on Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Recently I integrated Azure B2C to my Xamarin app. As per the requirement I want to allow user sign in with their Microsoft account. I followed the steps mention here - learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-msa-app In this article they selected web but I selected Mobile as I am working on mobile app. But when I go to azure portal, click run now button on sign up or sign in policies blade, then click Microsoft it gives me below error -

We're unable to complete your request

Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.

Here is the error URL -

https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=invalid_request&error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'redirect_uri'+is+not+valid.+The+expected+value+is+'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'+or+a+URL+which+matches+the+redirect+URI+registered+for+this+client+application.&state=

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!